# Use Metal to Efficiently Render a Scrolling Image

Tags: swift, image-processing, metal, metalkit

I would like to use Metal to efficiently render a particular type of time-varying image - namely an image which continuously scrolls vertically.  That is, each frame is exactly the same as the previous frame except shifted down by one row.  The bottom row scrolls off the screen and is discarded.  The top row is new data inputted from some Swift array.  My application uses real-time audio data to render a spectrogram - but this "rendering a scrolling image" is a general-purpose need with broad applicability.

The brute-force way to implement this is to store the data in an array and read the entire image array into the rendering screen for each frame - ignoring the fact that 99.9% of the data is already in the video memory buffer and simply needs to be accessed differently.

In the old days, when developers had direct access to the display's VRAM video memory, one could achieve this effect by simply incrementing the VRAM's row-access pointer by one for each frame (and writing in the top row's new data).  Today, OS's abstract the screen's buffer memory - but hopefully Metal provided a clever way of cutting through this abstraction to allow this low-level data shifting.

The SO question "Moving an Image using Metal Shader" ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920923/moving-an-image-using-metal-shader)) is helpful, but leaves me wondering what's the right approach.  Can someone please point me in the right direction to implement this?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you can't use a MTLTexture or MTLBuffer the same way that you would if did have direct access to VRAM?

Comment: You write a metal shader, where vertex function is simple, just returns a position and texture coordinates as is, then you write a fragment function, which takes 1. the output given by vertex, 2. your one row array and 3. the last texture that was on the screen, and may be size of the texture, now you use this size and texture coordinates returned by vertex shader to identify the index of row currently being rendered, then just sample out the appropriate color from either your new row data or previous texture. I.e if row==0 return that new data else sample color from texture at row-1.